# How to understand jstat -printcompilation output

Tags: java, jvm, jit, jstat

```
jstat -printcompilation pid
```

can get information about the last method that is compiled, like:

```
Compiled  Size  Type Method
     207     64    1 java/lang/CharacterDataLatin1 toUpperCase
     208      5    1 java/math/BigDecimal$StringBuilderHelper getCharArray
```

What's the third column mean?
I can't find detail info about 'Type'. How many types inclued?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jstat.htm#JSWOR734

oracle document dont' have enough info yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `Type` column corresponds to [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d17bf51f91371072a758e775136af946192e771b/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compileBroker.hpp#L149-L150) enum:

```
1 = normal_compile  // Regular JIT compilation
2 = osr_compile     // On-stack replacement
3 = native_compile  // Compiled wrapper for a native method
```

However, the values other than `normal_compile` are available only in debug builds of the JVM when `-XX:+CICountOSR` or `-XX:+CICountNative` option is [set](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/d17bf51f91371072a758e775136af946192e771b/src/hotspot/share/compiler/compileBroker.cpp#L2415-L2420):

```
  int last_compile_type = normal_compile;
  if (CICountOSR && is_osr) {
    last_compile_type = osr_compile;
  } else if (CICountNative && method->is_native()) {
    last_compile_type = native_compile;
  }
```

In practice this means that `Type` is always `1` with a regular JDK.